# Powershell Hashtable Retrieval Trouble

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am having trouble using a hashtable to map product codes to model names:

```
$modelList = @{}

$key = 48525748
$value = "Dell P2217"
$modelList[$key] = $model

$key = 65486855
$value = "Dell P2217"
$modelList[$key] = $model


$key = 65486856
$value = "Dell P2217"
$modelList[$key] = $model

$key = 51505066
$value = "HP 22-incher"
$modelList[$key] = $model

write-host WHYYYY:  $modelList[51505066]
write-host WHYY: $modelList.Get_Item(51505056)
```

All that the above writes out is the `WHY`.
Why can't it retrieve the items I just added?  Sorry, I know this is super basic but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: `$model` is NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It looks like you simply meant to assign `$value`, not `$model` to your hashtable entries**, which would explain why you get no output (an uninitialized variable is implicitly `$null` by default in PowerShell).
One way to detect such problems is to **make PowerShell report an *error* if you try to get the value of an uninitialized variable**, by **setting [`Set-StrictMode -Version 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode)** or higher.

---

However, **consider using a hashtable *literal*** in your case, which obviates the need for variables altogether:

```
$modelList = @{    
  48525748 = "Dell P2217"    
  65486855 = "Dell P2218"    
  65486856 = "Dell P2219"    
  51505066 = "HP 22-incher"    
}

$modelList[51505066]  # -> 'HP 22-incher'
```

Defining it on a single line is also an option, in which case you must separate the entries with `;`

```
$modelList = @{ 48525748 = "Dell P2217";  65486855 = "Dell P2217";  65486856 = "Dell P2217";  51505066 = "HP 22-incher" }
```

In terms of ***accessing* a hashtable's entries**, you have two syntax choices (in addition to calling the parameterized `.Item()` property / `.get_Item()` method):

- Index notation: `$modelList[51505066]`
- Dot notation (as with objects): `$modelList.51505066`

However, there are subtle differences - see below.

**Caveats**:

- **You're using *numbers* as keys**, whose specific type here is `[int]` (`System.Int32`), which PowerShell selected automatically based on the values.

  - While using numbers as keys works fine in principle, **if the number type is *different* than `[int]`, you may need to use an *explicit cast* in order to access such entries**:

    ```
    $ht = @{ 10L = 'ten' } # suffix 'L' makes the number a [long] (System.Int64)
    $ht[10] # !! FAILS, because 10 is an [int], so the key is not found.
    $ht[[long] 10] # OK - explicit cast matches the key's actual type
    ```
- **To use *string* keys, *quote* them**, e.g., `'65486855'`.

  - Index notation *always* requires quoting to access *string* keys:
    `$ht['65486855']`
  - By contrast, dot notation only requires quoting string keys if they *look like* a number (if they would be parsed as a number as an unquoted token):

    ```
    $ht = @{ '10' = 'ten'; 'a1' = 'a-one' } # string keys
    $ht['10'] # quoting required
    $ht.'10'  # ditto, because 10 without quotes would be a *number*
    $ht.a1    # quoting *optional*, because a1 is parsed as a *string*
    ```

Comment: I feel like this should be a default pssa rule (using non-string types as keys in hashtables).  As an aside, I had no idea you could suffix numbers in powershell like other languages (`10L`) to change the explicit type

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Use of non-string keys should definitely be deliberate choice. Aside from `L` for `[long]`, there's also `D` for `[decimal]` (as well as the binary-multiplier suffixes `kb`, `mb`, ...). Sounds like several more suffixes are coming: see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/7575 and https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7557

Answer (score 0):

As @mklement0 stated, you are assigning an unassigned variable (`$null`) to the value of each key. You simply need to replace `$model` by `$value`.

**Note:** You also were referencing a non-existing key in your `Get_Item()` call.

### Solution

```
$modelList = @{}

$key = 48525748
$value = "Dell P2217"
$modelList[$key] = $value

$key = 65486855
$value = "Dell P2217"
$modelList[$key] = $value


$key = 65486856
$value = "Dell P2217"
$modelList[$key] = $value

$key = 51505066
$value = "HP 22-incher"
$modelList[$key] = $value

write-host WHYYYY:  $modelList[51505066]
write-host WHYY: $modelList.Get_Item(51505066)
```